# Why does Event Viewer show a different framework version?

Tags: c#, .net, event-viewer

**Introduction**

My application originally targetted .NET framework 4. Now, I changed it to target .NET framework v4.6.1 as well as all its dependency projects and Rebuild it. In order to confirm that it is really targeting v4.6.1, I opened the .exe file using `notepad` and searched for the line `.NET Framework,version=v4.6.1`, which was found.

**Problem**

While trying to [debug an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847187/c-sharp-application-crashes-when-spamming-refresh-button-in-reportviewer), I found that Event Viewer lists my application's Framework Version as v4.0.30319 as can be seen below.

[image]

**Question**

Why is that so?

Comment: Bear in mind that 4.5 and 4.6 versions are in-place upgrades of 4.0 and still install into the 4.0.30919 directory on the machine. It may be that event viewer/.NET Framework error reporting don't choose to or are unable to distinguish here.

Comment: All versions after 4.0 are binary replacements for the earlier version, stored in the v4.0 folders. To Windows, it's still the same runtime. This means that if you install 4.6.2 on a system, all .NET versions that target 4+ will run on 4.6.2 from now on

Comment: In other words, there's nothing to fix. This is normal behaviour

Comment: Deleted my answer.. sorry for taking your time, and lesson learned, morning coffee before answering a question

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari that is always good advice ...